# Integrating Plaid API on Front End?

Tags: ios, c, swift, finance, plaid

My buddy and I are learning coding and are integrating Plaid's API currently. We've built out most of UI view controllers for our onboarding and sign up pages but are a bit confused about how Plaid's API ties into this.

We know from using other apps that on the front end there's a page or two dedicated to connecting the user's bank account, do we need to design the UI for this or does the API include this?

Thanks a lot!

Casper

Answer (score 0):

Plaid's API includes this, it's called Plaid Link. You can see what it looks like here: https://plaid.com/demo/